# New bounty design dislocates title

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, bounties

I think this is a very recent design change, because I've not seen it before:

[image: Screenshot of Code Review front page]

Where before a small box with the bounty value dislocated the title a couple of characters to the right, now the additional text saying how long until it expires dislocates the title by about a quarter of the width of the column.

I find that this makes it much harder to read the title, and is counterproductive to the goal of attracting attention.

Comment: @pppery this question was asked first, it was posted two hours earlier, it also has two answers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA that makes no sense, it doesnt matter what is asked first, its about the best answer. Thats obviously on the other Q.

Comment: @Luuklag It makes sense to me that the more complete answer should have been posted on the question that was asked 2 hours earlier. Don't worry though, no one will look at any of the two posts in a week's time because the bug has been fixed. If it happens again, in five years' time, I doubt anyone will bother scavenging in the archives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This change was [a mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332051/235711) and has been reverted.

Comment: Could we get the expiration date/time in a tooltip instead?  That would be handy when browsing the "bountied" tab.

Answer (score 9):

I agree. It looks much better when the elements are `float: right;` instead:

[image]

That way, the bounty indicator stands out even more, since on desktop/laptop screens most titles don't occupy a complete line, so there's a lot of whitespace on the right.

Another problem with the current setup is that on sites with black/grayish question titles, like the screenshot (from [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)), the 'ends in x days' text has almost the same color and is visually less distinct. It's not as bad for sites with blue titles (see my screenshot, from Meta).