# Change the way expired bounties are shown in question lists

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, bounties, expired-bounty

There has been a change in how bounties are displayed in some of the question lists, and while there is [room for improvement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332030/new-bounty-design-dislocates-title) it looks odd for bounties which are in their grace period. It's probably better not to show 'grace period' at all.

[image]

Since this screenshot was taken from the Featured page, one can at least deduce from the other questions that it has something to do with bounties; but on the Interesting tab it's *really* confusing, especially if you're new to Stack Exchange. Moving the information to the right, as I proposed in the linked question, doesn't really help; at least the +50 label has a helpful tooltip "this question has an open bounty ...".

Comment: Can't it just be put in the same box as the bounty amount is in? Easiest fix IMO. I would even considering tagging this as a bug, rather than a FR.

Comment: Posted (earlier) on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388345/4751173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was there [by mistake](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332051/235711) and is gone now.

I guess this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in that I did change the way it's displayed but as you say, there is room for improvement in how we do these things.